# How can I run a final piece of code before a $q.all returns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have code that runs promises

```
phrasesUpdate = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(self.phrases, (ph, key) => {
        if (ph.statusId == Status.Dirty) {
            ph.createdDate
                ? promises.push(self.phraseUpdateSubmit(ph, key))
                : promises.push(self.phraseAddSubmit(ph, key));
        }
    });
    return self.$q.all(promises);
};
```

This code works, however I would like to run this code:

```
 self.phrases.forEach(function (phrase, index) { phrase.index = index; })
```

inside of this function before returning.

Is there some way that I can fit this into the function?

Comment: Side note: In your code above, you're using only arrow functions or (with that last line you want to add) functions that don't use `this`. So there's no need for `var self = this;` at all, just use `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `then`:

```
return self.$q.all(promises).then(result => {
    // Your last thing goes here
    return result;
});
```

---

Re your edited question: I believe this is how you integrate that line into the code:

```
return self.$q.all(promises).then(result => {
    self.phrases.forEach(function (phrase, index) { phrase.index = index; });
    return result;
});
```

(I'm assuming here that the `phraseUpdateSubmit` and `phraseAddSubmit` modify `self.phrases`, which is why we're waiting to do this until after the promises they return complete.)